# unable to position carousel-control-next in card-deck

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap to create a carousel and using card-deck. The problem is my carousel-control-prev and carousel-control-next are overlapping on the text in the card I have created. I am a newbie so please excuse if I have missed anything. This is in a container class.

I have tried using below css but it does not work:

> .carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next{ align-self:
>   flex-start; }
>
> .card-deck{ bottom-margin: 10px; padding: 10px; }

[snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to6FH.png)